# onOptionsItemsSelected cannot be overridden and is unused?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menuitem

So I've been searching the internet for hours and cannot find a solution. It would appear I am having two issues with this code, the first one being the @Override for onOptionsItemsSelected (Method does not override method from it's superclass) and second being the onOptionsItemsSelected itself. onOptionsItemsSelected tells me the method is never used, which I thought might be why I am having the issue with @Override. I'm just not sure what it is I am overlooking. I have provided the java code below, if the xml code is needed let me know and I'll post it asap. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.main_navigation;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WalletActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallet);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override  ///First issue is here and 2nd issue is right below this line
    protected boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        final int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_custom_button) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `onOptionsItemSelected` - Item, not Items.

Answer (score 0):

For the First issue: Change the method scope from `protected` to `public`

For the Second issue: `onOptionsItemsSelected tells me the method is never used` This is a warning by Android Studio because there is no call to this method so it is useless

Answer (score 0):

Try the following source code instead of `onOptionsItemsSelected` class.

```
@Override  ///First issue is here and 2nd issue is right below this line
protected boolean onOptionsItemsSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_custom_button) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```